# How do i view / enable kernel logs on an ec2 instance (amazon linux)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, tcp, kernel

I've got a amazon ec2 server that i'm playing around with TCP settings in the sysctl.conf to increase the number of concurrent TCP connections it can handle, and i want to be able to view the kernel log to see any errors in the TCP stack, to ensure i've configured everything correctly.

I've read somewhere that i need to enable the kernel log first somehow. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

The AMI i'm using is:
amzn-ami-2011.02.1.x86_64

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon EC2, so could you please post the output of `cat /etc/issue` to see which distro you are running.

Comment: Amazon linux is based on centos / redhat AFAIK.

Comment: @quanta - When i did a cat /etc/issue i got the following: `[ec2-user@ip-10-112-97-251 ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2011.02.1.1 (beta)
Kernel \r on an \m`

Answer (score 9):

`dmesg` give you the kernel logs but it doesn't include the timestamp by default (it can be enable by recompiling kernel with `CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME=y`)

With [r]syslog, you can log all kernel messages to a file (with timestamp) by inserting a below line into `/etc/[r]syslog.conf`:

```
kern.*          /var/log/kern.log
```

Don't forget to restart [r]syslog daemon.

Comment: If i do `ps -ef | grep log` it shows that i'm running rsyslogd.

Comment: Is this how to restart rsyslog? `sudo service rsyslog restart`

Comment: OK. Or `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`.

Comment: Just adding to quanta's answer, on my `Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09`, `dmesg -T` prints a human readable timestamp at the beginning of each line.